# Kubernetes metrics-server doesn't provide all metrics or scale HPA

Tags: kubernetes, hpa, horizontal-pod-autoscaling, metrics-server, horizontalpodautoscaler

Following the example here https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/#autoscaling-on-metrics-not-related-to-kubernetes-objects, I have created installed metrics-server and modified it as follows:

```
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - metrics-server
        - --secure-port=8443
        - --kubelet-insecure-tls=true
        - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
        image: docker.io/bitnami/metrics-server:0.3.7-debian-10-r89
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: metrics-server
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8443
          name: https
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
```

My nodes are listed when queried:

```
kubectl get --raw "/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/nodes"
{"kind":"NodeMetricsList","apiVersion":"metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1","metadata":{"selfLink":"/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/nodes"},"items":[{"metadata":{"name":"eo-test-metrics-35lks","selfLink":"/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/nodes/eo-test-metrics-35lks","creationTimestamp":"2020-11-04T04:05:58Z"},"timestamp":"2020-11-04T04:05:28Z","window":"30s","usage":{"cpu":"770120208n","memory":"934476Ki"}},{"metadata":{"name":"eo-test-metrics-35lkp","selfLink":"/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/nodes/eo-test-metrics-35lkp","creationTimestamp":"2020-11-04T04:05:58Z"},"timestamp":"2020-11-04T04:05:25Z","window":"30s","usage":{"cpu":"483763591n","memory":"850756Ki"}}]}
```

But, the HPA targets remain 'unknown':

```
kubectl get hpa
NAME REFERENCE TARGETS MINPODS MAXPODS REPLICAS AGE
php-apache Deployment/php-apache <unknown>/50% 1 10 1 31m
```

Running top nodes works but top pods does not

```
kubectl top nodes
NAME                    CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%
eo-test-metrics-35lkp   93m          4%     934Mi           30%
eo-test-metrics-35lks   166m         8%     1053Mi          33%
```

Top pods return error `error: Metrics not available`:

```
 kubectl top pods
W1104 11:19:27.854485   62798 top_pod.go:266] Metrics not available for pod default/php-apache-d4cf67d68-blt2c, age: 13h1m51.854463s
error: Metrics not available for pod default/php-apache-d4cf67d68-blt2c, age: 13h1m51.854463s
```

This is on Kubernetes server version `v1.19.3` and metrics server version `0.3.6`

The logs from metrics-server

```
E1104 21:21:56.496129       1 reststorage.go:160] unable to fetch pod metrics for pod default/php-apache-d4cf67d68-blt2c: no metrics known for pod
E1104 21:22:10.945091       1 reststorage.go:160] unable to fetch pod metrics for pod default/php-apache-d4cf67d68-blt2c: no metrics known for pod
E1104 21:22:26.496814       1 reststorage.go:160] unable to fetch pod metrics for pod default/php-apache-d4cf67d68-blt2c: no metrics known for pod
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is resolved when Docker 19.03 is used on Kubernetes version 1.19 in relation to this upstream issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/94281

Answer (score 0):

Use this version of metrics server

```sh
git clone https://github.com/kodekloudhub/kubernetes-metrics-server
kubectl apply -f kubernetes-metrics-server
```

Then follow the same instructions as mentioned in [this link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/)

It will increase the number of pods as the load goes up

*BUT* I noticed the autoscaler does not scale down the deployment upon the load stopping. It might take some time until it scales down again

**Note**: This version of metrics server could only be used in a dev or learning environment.

I used [Katakoda environment](https://katacoda.com/courses/kubernetes/launch-single-node-cluster) for testing the answer.